# Render onetoone relationship in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, formset

I have 2 models:

```
class ModbusDevice(models.Model):
    ixModbusDevice = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sModbusName = models.CharField(verbose_name='Device Name',max_length=100)
    iPort = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Port')
    iSlave = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Slave ID')
    sIP = models.GenericIPAddressField(verbose_name='IP Address')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'TModbusDevice'

class BACnetDevice(models.Model):
    ixBACnetDevice = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ixModbusDevice = models.OneToOneField(ModbusDevice)
    sIP = models.GenericIPAddressField(verbose_name='IP Address')
    iPort = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Port')
    iSubnet = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Subnet', blank=True)
    bStatus = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'TBACnetDevice'
```

As you can see each `BACnetDevice` is related to each `ModbusDevice` via one to one. What I'm trying to do is display a table with mixed fields from each model.

I want to display the `ModbusDevice` name along with `sIP`, `iPort` and `iSubnet` from my `BACnetDevice` model like this(somewhat what i had working):
[image]

I'm having difficulty with rendering the model's formset foreign key field

I've tried this so far in my view:

```
BACnetFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ModbusDevice, BACnetDevice, fields=('sIP','iPort','iSubnet',))
bacnet_forms = BACnetFormSet()

return render(
    request,
    'app/create_bacnet.html',
    context_instance = RequestContext(request,
    {
        'title':'Create BACnet Device',
        'tag': 'create_bacnet',
        'bacnet_forms': bacnet_forms
    })
)
```

Comment: Your question only talks about "displaying", but your mockup seems to show a form and your code also uses forms. Do you want to display, or edit?

Comment: In my db I have existing `ModbusDevice` rows. I want to create a form for each instance in my db along with empty `BACnetDevice` fields. What I'm trying to do is create a `BACnetDevice` instance and save it to the db using the ModbusDevice pk  since each `BACnetDevice` references 1 `ModbusDevice`